# Why does Scrollspy target the outer div instead of the ul?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my confusion is that the Scrollspy is targeting the outer div instead of the actual element it is modifying. I'm trying to understand *why* that is the case?

The code in question is line 12 and 89-90 here:

http://4f7ba83874222b00ae84-8c55136fa379d9b2d1adde446f45d068.r28.cf2.rackcdn.com/scrollspy.html

Tried my best to include relevant part here:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                <h1 id="p_1">Part 1</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et felis consequat velit sollicitudin fermentum....
                </p>
                <h1 id="p_2">Part 2</h1>
                <p>
                    Maecenas massa eros, aliquam id nisi ut, venenatis eleifend diam....
                </p>
                <h1 id="p_3">Part 3</h1>
                <p>
                    Quisque id luctus tortor, a scelerisque nulla....
                </p>
                <h1 id="p_4">Part 4</h1>
                <p>
                    Nam sed volutpat sapien....
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked affix">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#p_1">Part 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p_2">Part 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p_3">Part 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#p_4">Part 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually target parent element of any Bootstrap navigation component.
It'd work too if u put the data-target to the ul nav class..

Comment: So how does Bootstrap know which is which? Does it search down the DOM tree?